# How to code so that the date automatically changes?

Tags: php, date

How can I modify the following code so the year automatically would change each year?

> ```
> </div>
> </div>
> </div></div>
> <div class="footer">
>   <p>Copyright 2023 </p>
>   <a href="#" class="go-up"></a> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Meaning I won't need to manually change the Copyright 2023 next year to Copyright 2024.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

I don't know how to make the date modified automatically based on the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. And maybe your question will be solved.

```
<div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?> </p>
    <a href="#" class="go-up"></a> 
</div>
```

Replace this code and the date() function will dynamically get the current year.